# Generic template ADT for dummies

Tags: java

I need to write a sorted set over an binary search tree, the problem is, I don't know  how I can use abstract type and compare for those 2 objects in the context, because i need to have  my own comparator declared.

I got so far but somehow i get stuck, since Compararable type i think is out of the question because of my own comparator method.

static node class:

```
static class  BinaryNode<ElementType> {
    ElementType element;
    BinaryNode <ElementType> right;
    BinaryNode <ElementType> left;

    public BinaryNode(ElementType elm) {
        ElementType element = elm;
        right=left=null;
    }
}
```

method example where I get confused:

```
   private BinaryNode find( ElementType x, BinaryNode t ) {
        while( t != null ) {
            if( x.compareTo( t.element ) < 0 )
                t = t.left;
            else if( x.compareTo( t.element ) > 0 ) // is done with overrite of the comparable method, any Ideas please?
                t = t.right;
            else
                return t;    // Match
        }

        return null;         // Not found
    }
```

Comment: How could I make java like ElementType comparable in functions, using a declared comaprator in a generic way

Comment: What is the declaration for `ElementType`? And what is this "declared comparator" that you refer to?

Comment: With a second look at your code, I think `ElementType` is simply the type parameter for your `BinaryNode` class. Is that correct? If so, you can change it to `BinaryNode<ElementType implements Comparable>`.

Comment: hmm not ok, implements is for interface i think you ment extend but still not solving that problem :\

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a wildcard

```
class  BinaryTree <ElementType extends Comparable<ElementType>> { 
    private class  BinaryNode <ElementType extends Comparable<ElementType>> { 
           BinaryNode<ElementType> left,right;
           ElementType value;
           public BinaryNode(ElementType value, BinaryNode<ElementType> left ,  BinaryNode<ElementType> right) {
                  this.value = value;
                  this.left = left;
                  this.right = right;
            }
     }
}
```

I also believe that you can actually omit the generic type parametar altogether in the inner class BinaryNode.

Comment: not fising it, `ound mismatch: The type ElementType is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <ElementType extends Comparable<ElementType>> of the type BinarySearchTree<ElementType>.BinaryNode<ElementType>
 The constructor BinarySearchTree.BinaryNode(ElementType) is undefined`